# Product measure

Tags: measure-theory

Is it true that a probability measure on a product of (say two) measurable spaces is the product probability measure of its projections? If not in general, is it true in some particular case?

P.S: I would appreciate if you could tell me some good book where such questions are considered, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, consider the (appropriately scaled) linear Lebesgue measure on diagonal of the unit square (or a cube, if you want larger products). The projections will be the standard Lebesgue measures, and with respect to the product measure the diagonal has measure zero.

It's certainly true in case where the measure on the product equals some product measure, for instance in case of the usual (multidimensional) Lebesgue measure, or the Haar measure of Cantor cube. Indeed, product measure is constructed in such a way that projections return the original measures.

Comment: The diagonal is the product of what spaces?

Comment: Diagonal isn't the product, it's a subset of a cube...

Comment: The diagonal of $X\times X$ is $\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general. For instance, consider the (somewhat silly) case in which you flip two coins: the first is fair, but the second outcome always matches the first.  The product measure would give a probability of $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ that you get, say, heads on the first coin and tails on the second; the joint distribution, however, assigns this event probability 0.

This pattern is not a coincidence: if you have random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, their joint measure is the product measure of their marginal measures if and only if they are independent.